# Third-Party Code and Git

Tags: objective-c, git, cocoa

When developing iOS applications, I frequently use third-party code from GitHub and reusable  classes I created myself. What I have been doing is cloning the source code into a specific folder somewhere in `~/Documents`, where I kept all the library code. Then I would drag the source files into the Xcode project and code away, with a local Git repository keeping track of the changes in my own source code. So far so good, but I recently found a severe problem: I wanted to switch back to a older version of my Xcode project and found that it did not compile anymore because it used an older version of the third-party code, and nowhere had I stored which version it used!

How is this problem usually solved? I have looked briefly into Git submodules, but I'm not sure if it's the right thing. I also briefly read about CocoaPods, but could I also use that for libraries I created myself?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is actually solved with [git submodule](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Tools-Submodules): the idea is to reference an *exact* commit for each submodule you need, allowing you to go back in the history, and find the *coherent* set of commits you need for your project to compile *then*.
(More in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1979167/git-submodule-update/1979194#1979194))

However, that does require a slight change in your working tree structure, since each submodule would become sub-directories of the parent repo which represents your project.

Note also that it (git submodule) is useful for *source* dependencies.
CocoaPods would be more for building the binaries you depend on (*binary* dependency).